# Directive subscription doesn't fire despite the subject calling next

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-directives

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/KfPfVSbZm087uIPvFEkM?p=preview

I've got a service which acts as an api for a modal component, and then I got a directive which can be used to add a class to any element when the modal is open. However the subscription inside the directive doesn't fire no matter what I do.

I've tried using both `Subject` and `BehaviorSubject` but none works.

Service:

```
@Injectable()

export class ModalApiService {

  constructor() {}

  private states = new Subject<any>();

  states$ = this.states.asObservable();

  open(id: string, template?: string): void {
    this.states.next({isOpen: true, id: id, template: template});

    // This runs as expected
    console.log(true);
  }

  close(id: string): void {
    this.states.next({isOpen: false, id: id});
  }
}
```

Directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[modalState]'
})

export class ModalStateDirective implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

  constructor(private modalApi: ModalApiService) {}

  private modalSubscription: Subscription;

  @HostBinding('class.modal-open')
  isOpen: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.modalSubscription = this.modalApi.states$.subscribe(
      state => {
        this.isOpen = state.isOpen;

        console.log(this.isOpen)
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.modalSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use **`BehaviourSubject`**, it works and it will hit the **`subscribe function`**. But still unable to identify why do we have **`undefined value`** of **`object properties`** when I m able to log the object properly.

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

private states = new BehaviorSubject<any>();
states$ = this.states.asObservable();
```

**Working but not working : https://plnkr.co/edit/YspSd2fKvktPEk6bL2hF?p=preview**

Comment: It doesn't work with BehaviorSubject in my real app.. So idk what the hell is going on here.

Comment: Its hard to say. Double check your code and rxjs  or rxjs operators imports.

Answer (score 1):

The subscription doesn't fire, because directives ngOnInit is raised after the app's ngOnInit. Thus the `next` is called *before the subscription in the directive*. This can be proved with simple button that calls service open/close methods:

```
toggle() {
  this.modalApi.open('someid');
  this.modalApi.close('someid');
}
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/MJET0Jw12SLx0BChAiWz?p=preview

If you really would like to start with open Dialog using the service, then I would suggest you use **ReplaySubject**. This should give you all emits before the first subscriptions:

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/replaysubject.md

Here is a demo using the ReplaySubject:

https://plnkr.co/edit/boHGQhc7atMTOTPLMnO0?p=preview

Comment: It's just for demo purposes. In my real app it's called with the click of a button :/

Comment: @Chrillewoodz, I'll update the answer with a working demo showing the usage of ReplaySubject. As you can see, the console.log(state.isOpen) is called on load.